# How to quote a forward slash in a WebClient url?

Tags: c#, url, webclient

I am using WebClient to connect to a data source on the web and I need to provide a user name and password.  The user name can contain a forward slash.  However, if this is in the connect string it does not work. 
My code:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient)
{
      data = client.DownloadString("https//myURL" + userID + password)
```

This all works fine for a userID such as "va2fsf" but not for one containing a forward slash such as  `9k/vo1dsk`.
How do I handle this? I tried using `%2F as in 9k%2Fvo1dsk` but this doesn't work.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is your target .NET framework? this problem exists if you are targeting the .NET 4.0 framework. It goes away if you target the .NET 4.5 framework. Try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
data = client.DownloadString("https://myURL" + 
                              HttpUtility.UrlEncode(userID) +
                              HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password))
```

Comment: Great going to try this now.  Thanks I'll let you know.

Comment: Hi,Well it seems that it still doesn't work.  If there is a forward slash in the userid it fails.  Is this a server issue?

Comment: As it turns out, one does not need to encode a forward slash when it is a parameter as mine was. The errors I received were not related to the forward slash.